# mysql php grouping by a category name

Tags: php, mysql

Quick brief: Just now I currently get a list of results by using the below code. I am trying to group my `u_feed` results by `c_feed` `id`'s.

`$uid = '15';`

`SELECT u.uid, u.fid, f.url,f.icon, u.title, f.favicon, f.domain FROM u_feed u INNER JOIN feed f ON f.id = u.fid WHERE u.uid = '$uid'`

I have just added a table called `c_feed` which will hold the `name` and `uid` of each category. The `u_feed` table will then use the column `cid` to check `c_feed` for the `id`.

**table c_feed**

[image]

**table feed**
[image]

**table u_feed**
[image]

I tried 
`SELECT u.uid, u.fid, f.url, f.icon, u.title, f.favicon, f.domain, c.cname
FROM u_feed u
INNER JOIN feed f ON f.id = u.fid
INNER JOIN c_feed c ON c.id = u.cid
WHERE u.uid = '15'
LIMIT 0 , 30`

This only returned 
[image]

But it should have 11 rows (image below without grouping)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is your `inner join` which only include the record if there is an associated record in c_feed. So the only records you got back were the two **WITH** a `cid`.

You might be looking for `left join`s.

```
SELECT u.uid, u.fid, f.url, f.icon, u.title, f.favicon, f.domain, c.cname 
FROM u_feed u 
LEFT JOIN feed f ON f.id = u.fid 
LEFT JOIN c_feed c ON c.id = u.cid 
WHERE u.uid = '15' LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: Because some rows for `cid` are `0` they don't show up in the results, so I have used something like this but also another query for the `0`